# Xcode performSegueWithIdentifier not working

Tags: storyboard

I want to switch a scene according to a user status(which is NSUserDefaults value), so I am using two view controllers and segues. But it is not working. I believe there is something wrong in my code. Please help. thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

//sleep(5);
NSString *usercode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"usercode"];
if([usercode isEqualToString:@""] || usercode == nil){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"usercode start: key=%@", usercode);
}else{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loggedInSegue" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"usercode start: not null key=%@", usercode);
}
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"loginSegue"])
{
    NSLog(@"delegated");
    //loginViewController *loginController = [segue destinationViewController];        
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[segue destinationViewController] class]));
    //controller.delegate=self;
}else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"loggedInSegue"]){
    NSLog(@"logged in delegated"); 
}
}
```

Comment: fix the problem. it should be in -(void)viewDidAppear, instead of -(void)viewDidLoad.

Comment: put this as an answer below and 'Accept' it. so that the other fellows who will see this question will get to see the answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be in

```
-(void)viewDidAppear
```

instead of

```
-(void)viewDidLoad.
```